# How to use the FilterBy for multiple data in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

That is controller chat.js code

```
 queryParams: ['offer_id'],
 offer_id: null,
 filteredChat: Ember.computed('model.@each.offer_id','offer_id',
   function() {
    return this.get('model').filterBy("offer_id" ,this.get("offer_id")).filterBy("id", this.get("offer_id"))
  }),
```

I am filtering the chat with offer_id.

I want to know that can i use the filterBy like this two times
and that is my route chat.js code

```
queryParams:{
  offer_id:{
   refreshModel : true
 }     
},
model(params) {
      return this.store.query("chat", params).then(() => {
       let model = this.store.peekAll("chat")
       return model
  })
 },
```

My Model chat.js

```
message: attr('string'),
offer_id: attr('string'),
stamp: attr('string'),
type: attr('string'),
```

Comment: Yes. you can use it since `filterBy` returns matched array

Comment: It would be good if you can share errors or problem you are facing in your code ?

Comment: Bro i gve the params offer_id and i am selecting data. some id from the model is same with that params offer_id and some offer_id from the model is same with that params offer_id so i want to know how to filter the different data from the same model.

Comment: Your current `model` code doesn't look correct to me. why do you need to `peekAll` when you do `query` ?. Do keep in mind `peekAll` return live array which means whenever store updated then it will also be updated. I am not sure I understand your problem though.

Comment: There is no errors bro but only data not showing when using two filterBy. and data show when i use only one of the filterBy. I can't use two filterBy

Comment: then I would say there is no result matched your filter condition. `filterBy` chaining will work. so I would encourage you to put `debugger;` in `filteredChat` computed property, or split your code and test something like this `let first =  this.get('model').filterBy("offer_id" ,this.get("offer_id"));  let second = first.filterBy("id", this.get("offer_id")); console.log('first ',first,' second ',second);` check and compate the result yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but be careful, your dependency string is wrong. You should include `model.@each.id` as well.

Also you need to understand that this will result in an array with the items that both the `offer_id` **and** the `id` are the same and exactly the `offer_id` you'r filtering on. This will **not** result in the items that either the `offer_id` **or** the `id` are equivalent to you filter `offer_id`.

If you want the **or** version you could do this:

```
return [
  ...this.get('model').filterBy("offer_id" ,this.get("offer_id")),
  ...this.get('model').filterBy("id" ,this.get("offer_id")),
]
```

---

so you see, if this works depends absolutely on what you expect.

Comment: Bro i gve the params offer_id and i am selecting data. some id from the model is same with that params offer_id and some offer_id from the model is same with that params offer_id so i want to know how to filter the different data from the same model.

Comment: Okay, if you still have questions after reading my answer, maybe you could post an example array and say which items you want after filtering?